# Transfer VS2010 window settings from design to debug?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How do I transfer the window layout in Visual Studio 2010 from design mode to debug mode? I have a window layout I am fairly happy with in design mode, and would prefer to not have to do all that work all over again just to change a few details in it.

I found [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838109/how-can-you-stop-visual-studio-rearranging-its-windows-when-debugging) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57345/how-can-i-stop-losing-all-my-ide-window-position-when-pressing-the-start-debuggin) that were kinda-sorta about this, but not quite.

Any suggestions? I know about import/export settings and use it religiously (switching between single-monitor and dual-monitor window layouts) but that doesn't really help me in this particular situation, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

VS shell's ViewManager serializes the window profiles in your %AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0 directory in *.winprf files (which are basically just XAML files).

There are 5 profiles: Debug, Debug-Fullscreen, Design, Design-Fullscreen and NoToolWin (when no solution is open). You can experiment with replacing your Debug*.winprf with your Design*.winprf.

Please note that any manual modification of these files is entirely unsupported, so if you break something, you're totally on your own here.

Answer (score 0):

Export your settings:

1. Choose General Settings/Window Layouts (in VS 2013) and save the file.
2. Open the file in an XML editor (or whatever... it's an XML file)
3. Find /UserSettings/Category/Design/WindowProfile and copy the entire node. 
     -- This assumes your Design view is the one you want to use for both modes.
4. Find /UserSettings/Category/Debug/WindowProfile and replace it with the one you copied from Design.
5. Save and re-import.

I have one of these settings files for home, remote, and office.